# Skip catching errors in a shell script

Tags: shell-script, error-handling

I have a script which compile a program. This program first compiles the source code using `configure && make` commands, then runs some tests using `make test`. This script also uses `set -e` to catch errors.

Now, what I want to do is keep `set -e` set in the script and still continue running the script when `make test` encounters some errors. I have tried using `make -k test` to make the tests run even when it encounters errors, but it is caught by the `set -e` command and it is stopped.

I also know which tests are going to fail, so is there any way to tell the script to skip catching these errors.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
make test || true
```

e.g.

```
#!/bin/sh
set -e
echo hello
make test || true
echo done
```

Will result in

```
hello
make: *** No rule to make target `test'.  Stop.
done
```

In this case the failure was a missing rule (no Makefile :-)) but we can see the script continues.

Answer (score 2):

`set -e` can be flipped with `set +e`.

```
#!/bin/sh
set -e
configure && make
set +e
make test
...
```

Comment: Isn't there any other way to do it? As in more robust way?